# sub menu to hide on other parent menu click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was building a menu with sub menus for a custom parallax website. On clicking the parent menu; the sub menus stay displayed which is needed. What I want to do is to hide the sub menus when other parent menu items are clicked. I could really use some help as Im new to j query. Here is my code..

HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li data-slide="2">estate
        <ul class="navigation2">
            <li data-slide="2">land</li>
            <li data-slide="3">varietal</li>
            <li data-slide="4">people</li>
            <li data-slide="6">practices</li>
            <li data-slide="9">future offerings</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-slide="10">about</li>
    <li data-slide="13">location</li>
    <li data-slide="14">contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navigation {
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
.navigation li {
    display:block;
}
.navigation li:hover, .active {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.navigation2 {
    position:fixed;
    text-align:right;
    left:50%;
}
.navigation2 li {
    color:#000;
}
.navigation2 li:hover, .active {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.navigation2').hide();
$('.navigation').children().click(function () {
    $(this).children('.navigation2').slideToggle(1000);
}).children('.navigation2').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your click event, hide the current li's siblings' navigation2 elements.

```
$('.navigation').children().click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().children('.navigation2').hide(); //add this line
    // rest of your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your sub menus a class like 'submenu'

then, on clicking any of the parent menus, you can hide all of the submenus by doing:

```
$('.submenu').hide();
```